# Factors affecting Capacitance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, capacitance, conductors

In case of a parallel plate capacitor, I knew that capacitance is affected by area, separation between plates and dielectric medium. so am I right with the idea in the given picture?[image]

Comment: Yes , relative position is pointing towards the intervening distance ...

Comment: I edited the question @Nehal I asked something wrong before

Comment: If all the factors are equal in both , then $ C_1 = C_2 $ ... But I think you should not waste your privilege of asking question regarding such topic , cause it's not **so** conceptual , rather the **chat room** is suitable for such queries ...If you have reputation. ..:P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capacitance can be calculated by:

$$C=\varepsilon_0 \varepsilon \frac Ad$$

where $\varepsilon_0$ is vacuum permittivity, $\varepsilon$ the material's (dielectric's) relative permittivity, $A$ plate area and $d$ plate separation.

You are asking about $d$, if I am not mistaken. Think of electrons as small balls on this context:

- Turn on the battery, and the voltage "pushes" electrons from the negative terminal. They move until reaching the capacitor plate, where they can move no further. And the same amount of positive charge is simultaneously induced on the opposite plate. They now accumulate as more and more electrons arrive. An electron repels other electrons arriving, so accumulating electrons means growing repulsion. This gradually reduced the current. Soon the repulsion balances put the battery "push" and all current stops flowing.

The capacitance $C$ is a measure of how much charge that has been accumulated (stores) now.

- The area of the plates allows for  electrons to spread out before having the repulsion accumulated. More electrons can be stored, so larger $A$ will increase $C$.
- And now to the separation. When positive charge is induced on the other plate, the two plates will now attract each other strongly. The electrons on one plate are "pulled in" by the positive plate. Think of this "pull" as helping out the battery "push". The battery gets help so it spends a bit less effort on pushing. This allows for it to push a few more electrons to the plate before having spent all its effort. The closer the plates are (the smaller the separation $d$), the higher the "pull" and thus the bigger the help to the battery, allowing for the battery to push even more electrons up there before having spent all effort. Therefore, smaller $d$ increases the amount of stored charges and thus $C$.

> [...] C is determined purely geometrically, by shape and size of the system

This is not true. Geometry is not the only factor. Geometry (plate area and separation) is one factor, while another is the dielectric material in between the capacitor plates. This is described in the text, point 10.

Comment: oops sorry I was asking something different, i will edit the question soon

Comment: I have edited the question , sorry for the previous question..

Comment: @PrathamArya I don't understand the new question. What exactly is the idea that the picture shows?